# Custom Thread names with ThreadPoolExecutor (NOT just the prefix)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I've found a couple threads with a pre-search, but they ALL (including online tutorials) state the solution is to use the thread_name_prefix parameter, which is NOT what I want.

I'm using the code below which works fine. As expected, all threads are named as "Access Rule Deletion_XXX". What I am trying to do is name each thread, not only with the thread prefix of my choice, but I'd like to append the "ar" value (a string) from the below code as well, basically so I can see what "access rule" it is currently processing with each thread.

Ideal Output for thread name would be: "Access Rule Deletion - SourceMatters Access_XXX" (where "SourceMatters Access" is some arbitrary access rule name)

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100, thread_name_prefix="Access Rule Deletion") as e:
    future_list = []
    for ar in existing_access_rules:
        future = e.submit(access_rule_deletions, ar)
        future_list.append(future)
```

Is this possible with the ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: You could inherit a class from `ThreadPoolExecutor` and copy method `_adjust_thread_count` from [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py) (or just copy the whole class) and modify the creation of the thread(name)s in it.